# How to decode my unicode html entities into string in java and how to export to excel?

Tags: java, excel, unicode

How to decode my unicode html entities into string in java and how to export to excel?
My code is here,

```
importExportXML.setTitle(rs.getString(3));
```

"  ஆல்ஃபா தியானம்  "

Once I export following result list to excel it shows uni-code(HTML entities). How to export excel with exact string using java?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Java's StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava() for decoding, then for exporting to Excel, you can either use CSV, or go the tab route. Each tab corresponds to a column, just append them wherever necessary.